# No output coming from log4net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net

I am trying to use log4net by following a few tutorials and reading the plethora of posts about people having problems with it, since I can not make it work properly.

I have this part right on top of my `.config` file

```
<configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log4net.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I added this line on my AssemblyInfo file

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)]
```

And tried using the logger inside mt service like this

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

or

```
private static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyService));
```

No file is ever created though, nor any other indication that something is happening at all.

How can I properly use this logger?

Comment: @fubo yes I simply didn't thought it would be useful adding that line of code to the question, I doubt I've made some error there.

Comment: does your application have writing access to the log-directory?

Comment: Yes it does, I've tried various locations and I know that at least in 'Temp' it does.

Comment: Is the assembly attribute contained in the startup project? Plus note this from the docs (their emphasis) - "Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**". Or just use `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in your startup code.

Comment: @stuartd I had that command at the start of my app but after reading a few other answers in SO I got the idea that I should remove it.

Comment: I think some people think assembly attributes are 'cool'. Which they are, I suppose, when they work. if you're using the default config file to put your config in, you don't need to specify `ConfigFile`, and I don't believe you can get `Watch` functionality [on the default config file] this way, you have to pass a `FileInfo` to  [`XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_ConfigureAndWatch_1.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Create a log4net DebugAppender to view the output of log4net in the Visual Studio output window which should give you some indications to the issue.

Add to the app.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- log4net configuration when running in debug mode. -->    
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />   
</appSettings>
```

Add a new debug appender to the log4net.config:

```
<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
  <immediateFlush value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
</appender>
```

And add the new appender to the log4net.config root:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
</root>
```

Run the application and view the Visual Studio output window to view the internal logging for log4net. If there is no output, then the log4net.config file is never loading.

Comment: It seems that all my log levels are set at false so this means that Im not correctly finding my configurations for the logger.